# Types in Union or Concat cannot be constructed with hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to run a query very similar to the following:

```
(from bs in DataContext.TblBookShelf
join b in DataContext.Book on bs.BookID equals b.BookID
where bs.BookShelfID == bookShelfID 
select new BookItem
{
        Categories = String.Join("<br/>", b.BookCategories.Select(x => x.Name).DefaultIfEmpty().ToArray()),
    Name = b.Name,
ISBN = b.ISBN,
BookType = "Shelf"
}).Union(from bs in DataContext.TblBookShelf
join bi in DataContext.TblBookInventory on bs.BookID equals bi.BookID
    select new BookItem
    {
          Categories = String.Join("<br/>", bi.BookCategories.Select(x => x.Name).DefaultIfEmpty().ToArray()),
          Name = bi.Name,
      ISBN = bi.ISBN,
      BookType = "Inventory"
});
```

I am receiving "Types in Union or Concat cannot be constructed with hierarchy" after the statement executes, I need to to be able to get a list of categories to display with each book.  If anyone could shed some light on a possible solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DataContext : Linq2Sql or Linq2EF ?

Comment: What is the base class of BookItem ?

Comment: Linq2Sql and BookItem is the base class.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are selecting a sub-sequence in the queries that you union (i.e. `b.BookCategories`). This is a LINQ 2 SQL limitation. It fails to translate this to SQL (because it would be very hard to do, so I guess the team chose not to support this).

Get rid of the sub-sequence select. Probably the easiest fix in this case is to execute the union client-side. Execute two server-side queries and merge the results.

Performance will be horrible anyway because of the sequence sub-select. You might want to research on how to fetch trees with L2S in an efficient way.

Comment: I know it's a bit late but you simply need to do the union in memory which is achieved by adding .ToList() to each part of the union. That is take Linq-to-SQL out of the equation. As long as  each section is efficient your overall query should also be efficient.